# Separating email addresses in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge data set that contains cells with multiple emails as depicted in the following picture:

[image]

As you can see that 3 emails are associated with X

I want to split the multiple emails and shift them down without affecting the other cells. The below picture illustrated the expected solution:

[image]

What is the best way to do that in Excel? What would be the formula for that?

Thanks,

Comment: Try with power query it's very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in power query

1. Click on Home tab in Power Query, select Split Column, by Delimiter.
2. Power Query will analyze your data and detect the delimiter.
3. Click on Advanced Options->Split Into section, choose Rows.